# How to write data into an offset which is not 512*n bytes using linux native AIO?

Tags: c, linux, aio

I'm writing some app like Bittorrent client to download file from net and write it to local file. I will get partial data and write to the file.

For example, I will download a 1GB file, I will get `offset 100, data: 312 bytes`, `offset 1000000, data: 12345`, `offset 4000000, data: 888 bytes`.

I'm using Linux native AIO(`io_setup`, `io_submit`, `io_getevents`), I found this

> When using linux kernel AIO, files are required to be opened in O_DIRECT mode. This introduces further requirements of all read and write operations to have their file offset, memory buffer and size be aligned to 512 bytes.

So how can I write data into some offset which is not 512 aligned?

For example, first I write 4 bytes to a file, so I have to do something like this:

```
fd = open("a.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_DIRECT, 0666);
struct iocb cb;
char data[512] = "asdf";
cb.aio_buf = ALIGN(data, 512);
cb.aio_offset = 512;
cb.aio_nbytes = 512;
```

Then I would like to append data after `asdf`:

```
struct iocb cb2;
char data2[512] = "ghij";
cb2.aio_buf = ALIGN(data2, 512);
cb2.aio_offset = 5;
cb2.aio_nbytes = 512;
```

It will give error when write

```
Invalid argument (-22)
```

So how to do it?

Comment: also look into preallocating the file, that will help performance for every future access.

Comment: I suspect you'd be better off just using `pwrite()` or `pwritev()` instead.

Comment: @Shawn thank you, but I understand pwrite is block I/O? Is posix AIO better?

Comment: [how to download files using linux](https://www.tecmint.com/linux-command-line-tools-for-downloading-files/)  This will tell you how to use `Wget` and `rTorrent` and a few other methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do what the driver would do if you weren't using `O_DIRECT`.  That is, read the whole block, update the portion you want, and write it back.  Block devices simply don't allow smaller accesses.

Doing it yourself can be more efficient (for example, you can update a number of disconnected sequences in the same block for the cost of one read and write).  However, since you aren't letting the driver do the work you also aren't getting any atomicity guarantees across the read-modify-write operation.

Comment: Hi, updated question.  it's not read the file and update and write. I'm downloading file from net and write it local file.

Comment: @garen96: Ok, that makes it easy.  Continue reading from the network until you have a whole block to write to disk.  Even 512 byte chunks are very very small for bulk file transfer, I'd be thinking of saving about 128kB at a time.  With a torrent you'll need a dozen or so buffers operating at a time, but you won't have random bits all over the place either.

Comment: so there's no way to write partially? I have to cache data in the memory and write to file once the data meets the requirement (offset/size is 512 aligned)?

Comment: @garen96: Correct.  It's you doing it, or the I/O library and/or driver doing it, and when you use `O_DIRECT` you're doing the buffer management

Answer (score 1):

You don't. **The Linux AIO API is not useful**, especially not for what you're trying to do. It was added for the sake of Oracle, who wanted to bypass the kernel's filesystems and block device buffer layer for Reasons™. It does not have anything to do with POSIX AIO or other things reasonable people mean when they talk about "AIO".

Comment: I see... Thank you. Maybe I should use POSIX AIO to do non-block IO? or should I just use pwrite?

Comment: Unless you'll be writing to storage that freezes your task in uninterrupible sleep for consequential amounts of time, use pwrite.